# Creating an object then redirecting to that objects path results in continuously running Object.new everytime the page is refreshed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, object, save

So I have a random Item generator, here is the code for ring.rb

```
class Ring < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user

  after_initialize :randomly_make_ring

  def randomly_make_ring
    #everything is figured during initialization
    #You can call instance.make_ring to do it at any time.

    #chance calculation for description
    random_description = rand(1000)

    case random_description
    when 0..500
      self.description = 'Silver'
    when 501..800
      self.description = 'Gold'
    when 801..1000
      self.description = 'Diamond'
    end

    #Chance Calculation for Quality
    random_quality = rand(1000)

    case random_quality
    when 0..500
      self.quality = 'Sturdy'
    when 501..800
      self.quality = 'Elegant'
    when 801..1000
      self.quality = 'Platinum'
    end

    # Attributes according to the description
    case description
    when 'Silver'
      self.min_guard_roll = 1
      self.max_guard_roll = 2 + rand(4)
      self.min_pet_roll = 0
      self.max_pet_roll = 1
      self.min_trap_roll = 0
      self.max_trap_roll = 2
      self.buy = 20 + rand(15)      
    when 'Gold'
      self.min_guard_roll = 2
      self.max_guard_roll = 3 + rand(7)
      self.min_pet_roll = 1
      self.max_pet_roll = 3
      self.min_trap_roll = 1
      self.max_trap_roll = 3
      self.buy = 30 + rand(25)
    when 'Diamond'
      self.min_guard_roll = 4
      self.max_guard_roll = 5 + rand(10)
      self.min_pet_roll = 2
      self.max_pet_roll = 5
      self.min_trap_roll = 2
      self.max_trap_roll = 6
      self.buy = 80 + rand(48)
    end   

    # Attributes according to the quality
    case quality
    when 'Sturdy'
      self.min_guard_roll = self.min_guard_roll + 1
      self.max_guard_roll = self.max_guard_roll + (1 + rand(2))
      self.buy = self.buy + (10 + rand(6))   
    when 'Elegant'
      self.min_guard_roll = self.min_guard_roll + 2
      self.max_guard_roll = self.max_guard_roll + (2 + rand(3))
      self.buy = self.buy + (25 + rand(14))  
    when 'Platinum'
      self.min_guard_roll = self.min_guard_roll + 4
      self.max_guard_roll = self.max_guard_roll + (4 + rand(8))
      self.buy = self.buy + (45 + rand(25))  
    end

    # Generate display name
    self.display_name = quality + ' ' + description + ' Ring'

    # Generate Sell Value
    self.sell = self.buy * ((10 + rand(20)).to_f / (31 + rand(20)).to_f).to_f



  end

  attr_accessible :user, :active, :display_name, :description, :buy, :sell, :min_guard_roll, :max_guard_roll, :min_trap_roll, :max_trap_roll, :min_pet_roll, :max_pet_roll, :image
```

end

Now here is my controller and actions I have set up:

```
def create

@ring = Ring.new
@ring.user = current_user

@ring.save

@user = current_user
@user.gold = @user.gold - 25 
@user.save

redirect_to ring_path(:id => @ring.id)


end  

def show
    @ring = Ring.find(params[:id])
  end
```

The problem I am having is that whenever a ring is created, it brings me to a page to the show page but the ring has different attributes than the one that was saved to the DB.  So It's not grabbing the right ring and for reasons I don't understand, there is a new ring being generated everytime the page is shown or refreshed.  The same thing happens on any page where I bring up @ring to show it's properties.

The exact way I want this to work, is the user can look for a ring, this then brings up a random ring, they can either choose to buy it or look at a different one.  If they choose to buy it, it is theres, if they choose to look at a different one, the current one gets destroyed.

Can someone help me understand why this is happening and if there is a better way of setting this up?  Thanks!

Comment: Do you realise that after_initialize runs after your load an object from the database as well as when creating a new instance.

Comment: So how do I call up something without it running through the after_initialize?

Comment: If this is code you want to run when you create a new instance before_create might be more appropriate. Or don't use callbacks and call the randomly_make_method when needed.

Comment: Thanks Frederick, I will give that a shot here.

Comment: @FrederickCheung You should post that as an answer so this question can get resolved.

Answer (score 0):

The `after_initialize` callback runs every time an object is instantiated, whether you're doing `Ring.new` or fetching an object from the database with `find`. As it stands whenever you fetch an object from the database you're immediately overwriting all of its attributes with your randomly generated ones.

You could change your callback to being a `before_create` which would result in it running when the object is first saved or not make it a callback at all, calling it only when needed.